# powershell - Remove all variables

Tags: variables, powershell

I want to remove all **user-created** variables at the start of a script.

Currently I am doing `Remove-Variable -Name *` but it tries to delete all system variables as well, resulting in lot of error messages.

Any other way?

Comment: Why? It sounds like there is a better solution to your underlying problem

Answer (score 32):

Since all the system variables are read-only or constant anyway you can just silence the errors:

```
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But admittedly, you should probably exclude a few anyway:

```
Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0
```

Comment: When you run Remove-Variable as admin, it will remove those read-only variables as well, so it should be done with care, and proper care would probably mean not using Remove-Variable at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666863/powershell-ise-cannot-start-after-foolishly-deleting-all-variables?rq=1

Comment: @music2myear: Your PowerShell session is yours, admin or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Invoke a new instance of PowerShell, get the built-in variables, then remove everything else that doesn't belong.

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps.AddScript('Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name') | Out-Null
$builtIn = $ps.Invoke()
$ps.Dispose()
$builtIn += "profile","psISE","psUnsupportedConsoleApplications" # keep some ISE-specific stuff

Remove-Variable (Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object {$builtIn -NotContains $_})
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting all the user variables, start a fresh instance of PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> $x = 10
PS C:\> $y = 50
PS C:\> $blah = 'text'
PS C:\> Write-host $x $y $blah
10 50 text
PS C:\> powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> Write-host $x $y $blah

PS C:\>
```

User defined variables won't carry over into the new instance.

```
PS C:\> $bleh = 'blue'
PS C:\> Write-Host $bleh
blue
PS C:\> exit
PS C:\> Write-host $bleh

PS C:\>
```

Your variables won't carry back over into the calling instance, either.

You have a few options in terms of how to actually accomplish this.

1. You can always start the new instance yourself, of course:

   `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File myscript`
2. You could encode that command in a separate script and then only call that script, and not the companion one with the real code.

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on those variables. Anything that was not declared is just not used. If you need to pass things around, use parameters.

If you keep up to this principle, you would just overwrite your user-created variable and use it like it never existed.

This is **enterprise best practices** that let you infinitely scale your scripts. Not just in Powershell, but in any language which could have global variables, such as Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **hack** that will delete all variables except those created in your $profile. Note that this takes a few seconds to run, and there's a pretty good chance you could achieve your end goal in a more efficient way. You'll have to adjust the "15" in the select statement to correspond to the number of lines your profile script spits out. Or you could modify it to search for the first line from gv (get-variable).

```
$x=powershell -nologo -command "gv|out-string"
$y=($x|select -skip 15) -split "\s+",2
$varnames = $(for ($i=0;$i -lt $y.length; $i+=2) { $y[$i]})
rv i,x,y
gv | % {if ($varnames -notcontains $_.name) {rv $_.name -EA 0}}
```

Caveat: this won't delete variables created by Powershell hosts that specify an InitialSessionState that loads modules or executes scripts that create variables. However for normal Powershell and powershell_ise you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: This seems over engineered

Answer (score 1):

Using [Joey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680309/1028230) works well... perhaps too well. When I used within Visual Studio Code, for instance, [its `$psEditor` variable was removed and its integrated terminal started throwing errors](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3718).

To be clear, I was using `Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0` as part of *my* script before firing off the rest of the script to ensure it was in a clean situation, but it over-cleaned.

I got around this issue by adding `$psEditor` to the exceptions list like this:

```
Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference,psEditor | Remove-Variable -EA 0
```

**But that's kind of a whack-a-mole approach**, and there seem to be better ways, depending on how much control you have over the scripts in question.

#### A better solution

For instance, here's [a nice solution from SeeminglyScience](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3718#issuecomment-991227441) from that issue I raised in GitHub, though it essentially reduces to [the logic in ferrell_io's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40266400/1028230) with a few important improvements:

```
$existingVariables = Get-Variable
try {
    # your script here
} finally {
    Get-Variable |
        Where-Object Name -notin $existingVariables.Name |
        Remove-Variable
}
```

That says...

1. Remember every variable in scope from before I started.
2. Start my script.
3. Remove everything I left in scope.

That's a nice "leave it no worse than you found it" workaround.

---

Maybe worth mentioning that the VS Code integrated terminal leaving important variables around in scope isn't perfect, and [some responses to the issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3718#issuecomment-991247807) raised said they might change `$psEditor` to a constant of some sort so that `Remove-Variable` couldn't do something this accidentally destructive.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull the list of existing variable names into an array at the beginning of the script, then remove any newly added variables at the end of the script:

```html
### Start of script (store list of existing variable names)
$ExistingVariables = Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

<#
Script contents go here
#>

### End of script (remove new variables)
$NewVariables = Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object {$ExistingVariables -notcontains $_ -and $_ -ne "ExistingVariables"}
if ($NewVariables)
    {
    Write-Host "Removing the following variables:`n`n$NewVariables"
    Remove-Variable $NewVariables
    }
else
    {
    Write-Host "No new variables to remove!"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider changing the scope of you variables. Variables contained within a loop or function for example only exist inside that scope. As long as the variables are not created within the global or script scope, they won't persist after the script finishes. You can then just remove the global / script scope variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

Since I had this same issue as the OP when I first started, I figured I'd offer my way of handling this (to me this is the simplest & surefire way, which I have been using as my standards for years).

(BTW to answer the why for this, sometimes when you are testing out scripts, or rerunning several versions, you want to be able to clear out what you've done, without messing up PS, or having to relaunch a clean console each time. Also really useful when running loops - to only clear out that section of variables.)

Instead of using the offered answers (which I have seen the same in other questions/forums), what I do is this:

- Just prefix all of the variables that I set with a Grouping Letter (for various reasons) + the underscore character [ _ ]
- Then use that prefix + wildcard with the remove/get commands

**Examples - Simple:**

```
# Set Variables - String / Single Values:
$S_VarName1         = 'String Value 1'
$S_VarName2         = 'String Value 2'
# Set Variables - Arrays / Multi-Values:
$A_VarName2         = @('Array Value 1','Array Value 1')
# Set Variables - Calculated Values:
$C_VarName2         = ("$($S_VarName1)"_"$($S_VarName)")    

# Remove MY Previously set Variables - ALL:
Remove-Variable -Name ("*_*")
# Remove MY Previously set Variables - Certain Group(s) (Various versions depending on purpose):
Remove-Variable -Name  ("S_*")                      # Only Strings
Remove-Variable -Name  ("*_*") -Exclude ("A_*")     # All except Arrays
```

Similar can be done for hashtables, datatables, PSCustom Objects etc., or for specific purposes to make getting & removing MUCH simpler IMO.

**Example - Using with Loops:**

```
# i.e. keep the main variables [ S_* , A_*, C_*, etc. ]
# but remove ones pertaining to that loop iteration only.

ForEach ($A_VarName IN $A_VarName2) {
    # Remove MY set Variables - Previous Loop Iteration:
    Remove-Variable -Name  ("L1_*")
    # Set Variables - For THIS Loop iteration:
    $L1_LoopVarName3    = 'Loop - String Value 3'
    }
```

**This can also be useful when you want to show what variables you have set (for confirmation when testing etc.):**

```
# Get MY Set Varialbles - Strings / Single Values:
Get-Variable -Name ("S_*") | Select-Object Name,Value | Format-Table

Output:
Name       Value         
----       -----         
S_VarName1 String Value 1
S_VarName2 String Value 2
```

You can also use this same prefix/wildcard method for Getting the variables, then making simlar outputs for the more complex ones like arrays & hashtables etc.

Comment: You could also reset/declare/initialize the variables right before usage where they needs to be empty in your script to handle possible side effects. That would make your script more resilient if it exits and has to be restarted.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could make a list of all the variables you don't want to delete.

```
$DontDelete = '$','?','^','args',...,'WhatIfPreference'
```

Then delete the variables that are not on the Don't Delete list.

Answer (score -4):

You can't. You'll have to keep track of the available variables before the script started and remove any variables added after the script executed.