# Clear out powershell terminal variables

Tags: powershell

Say I have the following powershell script:

```
$hello = "Hello World"
Write-Output $hello
```

When I run it I get

> Hello World

Then I decide that I want my variable to be named `$helloWorld`:

```
$helloWorld = "Hello World"
Write-Output $hello
```

When I run that I get

> Hello World

What I want is for that to fail because I have not defined `$hello` (or at least write out an empty string).

I have seen some examples that try to record off all the variables before running and calling Remove-Variable on all the new ones after.  This seems like a lot of work.

I thought I would ask if today's powershell has a better solution.  **Basically I am looking for a command that will reset the terminal's variable memory back to the initial startup state.**

Comment: Variable:\ is a drive just like any other. You can get a list of the items prior to script and then just remove the items that don’t exist in the list after. That is far less work then maintaining a list of added variables

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) with `-Version 1` or higher, references to nonexistent variables cause an error, both in the current scope and its descendants:

```sh
Set-StrictMode -Version 1

$helloWorld = "Hello World"

# Causes a statement-terminating error, because $hello isn't defined.
Write-Output $hello
```

**Caveats**:

- The error is only a *statement*-terminating error, which means that script execution will *continue* by default.
- If `$hello` happens to be defined in an *ancestral* scope, *no* error will be reported, due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping.
- ***IDE* caveats**:

  - Unfortunately, the [obsolescent, Windows PowerShell-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) Windows PowerShell ISE *invariably* runs scripts dot-sourced, i.e. directly in a session's global scope rather than in a child scope, so that previous invocations can leave behind state that affect subsequent ones.

    - Applied to your example: if you initially defined `$hello`, ran the script, and then changed the variable to `$helloWorld`, running the script will still succeed even with a strict mode in effect, because the `$hello` variable is still around.
  - Using Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension unfortunately does that too *by default*, but you can configure it use a new, temporary session for each invocation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970578/45375).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of the exact situation of this, however here are some approaches I would use:

- `powershell` - create a new instance of powershell
- `Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680309/19001479)