# powershell How to clear variable cache of all variable at once

Tags: powershell

I clear variable cache in my powershell script using "remove-variable variable name"  . I wanted to know is there cmd to clear the variable cache of all variables in the script in one go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17680309/520612

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, apparently under some scenarios, you can munge things up a bit with over zealous variable clearing:
[Powershell ISE cannot start after (foolishly) deleting all variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666863/powershell-ise-cannot-start-after-foolishly-deleting-all-variables?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this at the top of you script, or in the profile:

```
$sysvars = get-variable | select -ExpandProperty name
$sysvars += 'sysvar'
```

And then do this at the end:

```
get-variable * |
 where { $_.name  -notin $sysvars } |
 Remove-Variable
```

You can also do this:

```
 get-variable -Scope script | remove-variable
```

but it may delete variables you didn't intent do if you're working in the ISE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `remove-item variable:* -force`, I guess.